# Collapse regions using user defined language

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to add a User Defined Language in Notepad++ to allow regions in my documentation file to be collapsible.

**Header Sample**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
-- [#]                     My Header                    [#] --
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to set it so that comments are `-- [` with exactly one Space. So I'm setting the Open and Close to `-- [` in hopes that everything in between two headers will collapse. This appears successful until I reach a section with a left bracket in it `[` then the syntax highlighting goes haywire. Is there some sort of trick I can do to get it to simply collapse everything between two Headers?

**Example**:

```
 1. --------------------------------------------------------------
 2. -- [#]                     My Header                    [#] --
 3. --------------------------------------------------------------
 4.
 5.
 6. Collapse Lines 4-8 (or 3-9 if 4-8 isn't plausible).
 7. Problem occurs with the following kind of line:
 8.      array[issueStarts] = here;
 9. --------------------------------------------------------------
10. -- [#]               My Other Header                    [#] --
11. --------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm not too picky on what can be seen, though I would prefer being able to see the header titles.

**Question**

- Is this a bug or am I missing something here? With `-- [` as the *open* and *close* comment tags, should it not collapse lines 3-9?
- How do I get it to ignore Left Brackets in the sections? Isn't the comments supposed to be looking for `-- [` not `[`?

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to use `-` for this purpose since `-` is supposed to be minus character in any programming language. So it is expected from Notepad++ not to obey what you have defined for it. You can try something like `/*-- [` and `] --*/`

Comment: It's not for programming, it's for documentation. Additionally it'll only apply when I tell it to, so there will be a case of that issue. I just want to be able to collapse my documentation headers via the description above.

Comment: SynWrite: can define such syntax. You can collapse header then.

Comment: I love you. It's collapsing so many things in so many situations I wanted collapsed. Didn't even have to define a language. Post an answer please.